# Button's embedded background doesn't work on webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a button in javascript and appending it to a HTML page

```
let dropDownButton = document.createElement('button');
dropDownButton.style.background = "url(/48.png)";
  dropDownButton.style.width = size+"px";
  dropDownButton.style.height = size+"px";
  given.append(dropDownButton);
```

With `48.png` being the local file I wanted to embed.
Currently, this code works in an [HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75E7J.png) page I declared (created and declared in manifest) but it doesn't work on a [webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cV0Gf.png) (example twitter, with the last empty button being the one I appended).

Why is this happening? Can I fix it or just go back to inserting a `img` element inside a button?

Comment: You set the image url to `/48.png`. I'm assuming it's looking for `https://twitter.com/48.png`. Check the network tab.

Comment: Hmmm, I checked the network tab, it's labeled `48.png` as a text/html type, and when opened it does go to a twitter page, yes. I used to use `url(48.png)` but that doesn't work in the HTML page, but `url(/48.png)` (since the js file is in another folder).
Is there a way to address this?

Answer (score 0):

Wait I fixed it.
Simply hardcode the `chrome.runtime.getURL` method to get local file into the syntax of `url()`

So instead of

`dropDownButton.style.background = "url(48.png)";`

use

`dropDownButton.style.background = "url("+chrome.runtime.getURL('48.png')+")";`